# React file upload button

Tags: forms, button, reactjs

I'm trying to work out a styling issue with my "Choose file" button.  Currently, when using Chrome at normal 100% zoom my button appears as follows:

[normal zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4NiZ.png)

However, if I zoom out to 90% or in at 110% it reverts to a generic looking gray button:

[generic styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcW2p.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: It is really hard to say without seeing your full code.

Comment: The code immediately responsible for the button displaying is:                <div className={classnames({
            "has-prefix": !!prefix,
            "has-postfix": !!this.props.postfix
          })}>
            {input}
          </div>

Comment: Alright I completely forgot to just upload an interactive code sample.  This illustrates the issue I'm having - if you try to zoom out or in the button uglifies: https://jsfiddle.net/af5kLc6c/